# No owin.Environment item was found in the context randomly appearing on one server in a load balanced environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I know that there are a whole bunch of questions related to this problem already here on Stack Overflow but I've tried pretty much anything that I've managed to find regarding this problem which in our case occurs randomly and occasionally between our two load balanced production servers (site still not live).

Our problem is that once in awhile (can be after a deploy or a application pool recycling, not really sure when it happens) one of our servers (can be anyone of the two randomly) will show the error message:

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context

and further down in the stack trace it says:

> An error occured when trying to create a controller of type "XYZ.Controllers.RegistrationPageController", Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor"

Which it does.

While one of the servers show this error message the other one is working just fine with the same code and configuration. Is there anything particular to think about with regards to a load balanced environment when it comes to owin and ASP.NET Identity?

I've tried all the ways that are available when it comes to OWIN Startup Class Detection that are explained here https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

- Naming Convention (Startup-class in namespace matching the assembly
  name)
- OwinStartup Attribute (on the Startup-class itself)
- The appSettings element in the Configuration file (pointing out the
  Startup-class in the appSettings element owin:appStartup)

All of these sort of work since one of the servers work and clearing the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder on the other server makes the problem go away but only temporarily.

Comment: Forgot to mention that emptying the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" fixes the problem on the server that shows this error message but I can't see a long term solution where emptying this folder is the way around this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what exactly you've tried, what works, what doesn't. For instance, the first question in the Related section includes an answer referencing `<appSettings><add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[Namespace].Startup, [AssemblyName]" /></appSettings>`. Have you tried that? We can't be sure.